# how to read a file from server in play framework

Tags: file, filesystems, playframework

I have the following file

```
/app/menus/menu1.yml
```

and I'd like to read it's contents

--

short answer:

```
fileContent = play.vfs.VirtualFile.fromRelativePath("/app/menus/menu1.yml").contentAsString();
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

PlayFramework is built using the Java language.

In your code, there is no restriction about the usage of the java API.
So, your file can be read using the standard java code, if you know the file absolute path:

```
java.io.File yourFile = new java.io.File("/path/app/menus/menu1.yml");
java.io.FileReader fr = new java.io.FileReader(yourFile);
// etc.
```

If you want to access a File in a relative path from your Play application, your can use the play "VirtualFile" class: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.1/play/vfs/VirtualFile.html

```
VirtualFile vf = VirtualFile.fromRelativePath("/app/menus/menu1.yml");
File realFile = vf.getRealFile();
FileReader fr = new FileReader(realFile);
// etc.
```

Comment: `VirtualFile.fromRelativePath` is undefined for play 2.1. What to use instead?

Comment: @MyTitle, any answer here? How about for Play 2.2?

Comment: What is the correct answer if the file is in a module?

Answer (score 11):

For Play 2.0 in Scala you want to use `Play.getFile(relativePath: String)`

Comment: As a Java developer you would use: Play.application().getFile(String filename)

Answer (score 2):

Play includes the [SnakeYAML](http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/) parser.  From their [docs](http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#Loading_YAML):

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
String document = "\n- Hesperiidae\n- Papilionidae\n- Apatelodidae\n- Epiplemidae";
List<String> list = (List<String>) yaml.load(document);
System.out.println(list);
```

> ['Hesperiidae', 'Papilionidae',
>   'Apatelodidae', 'Epiplemidae']

There is also a version of `Yaml.load` that takes an `InputStream`, which is demonstrated in this sample code: http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/source/browse/src/test/java/examples/LoadExampleTest.java

Comment: thanks for the tip, that was going to be precisely my next question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

From Play 2.6 this is now in Environment. And I suggest using either `.getExistingFile` which returns an option in case file does not exist. Or `.resource` which returns a URL to anything in the classpath only.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.Environment

```
 class Someclass @Inject (environment: play.api.Environment) {
 // ...

 environment.getExistingFile("data/data.xml").fold{
   // NO FILE. PANIC
 }{ file =>
   // Do something magic with file
 }
```