# How to load JSON file using Play with Scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I need to load a `JSON` file with a list of cities in one of my **controllers**, in order to pass it to a **view** afterwards.

I have placed the file here: `app/assets/jsons/countriesToCities.json`
(By the way: is this an appropriate location, or should I place it somewhere else?)

I have read the **docs** and I can see it is possible to create a `JsValue` from a string: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJson#Using-string-parsing

I want to create a `JsValue` in a similar fashion. The difference is that I want to load the content from a **file**, not from a string... I haven't found any code snippet on how to do this, unfortunately.
Do I have to use something else to read the file into a string and only then use the parse method on that string?

Code snippets with examples on how to do this in the answers will be highly appreciated! :)

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to read a file from server in play framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519828/how-to-read-a-file-from-server-in-play-framework)

Comment: Not really a duplicate @Mr.V. . But together with Dylan's answer, I think I will manage to solve it! Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is how I managed to solve it:

```
val source: String = Source.fromFile("app/assets/jsons/countriesToCities.json").getLines.mkString
val json: JsValue = Json.parse(source)
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: `Json.parse` can read directly from a stream, so it's better to use the `InputStream` version rather than getting the lines, making a string out of them, and then parsing it.

Comment: The `.getLines` is not necessary here. Also, it'd be better to close the result of the `fromFile` call (a `io.Source` instance).

Answer (score 27):

Looks like the comment about the possible duplicate is how to read a file from your app/assets folder. My answer is about how to parse Json from a stream. Combine the two and you should be good to go.

[`Json.parse`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Json$) accepts a few different argument types, one of which is `InputStream`.

```
val stream = new FileInputStream(file)
val json = try {  Json.parse(stream) } finally { stream.close() }
```

P.S. When you can't find what you're looking for in the written docs, the [API Docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#package) are a good place to start.

Comment: `FileInputStream` belongs to `java.io`, but I am using Scala + Play, not Java + Play. Do I really have to use the `java.io`, or is there any other way?

Comment: Short answer is no. Long answer: Scala doesn't have much built-in functionality for IO. The `scala.io.Source` object is your closest bet - you could use that to load a file to a string, then pass that string to `Json.parse`. You could also look into other libraries with IO solutions, but that seems like too much effort to replace two lines of code.

Comment: I should note that since you are using Scala + Play, you are really using Scala + Java + Play. You can still use `java.io` without losing Scala.

Answer (score 6):

From Play 2.6, Environment has the `getExistingFile`, `getFile`, `resource` and `resourceAsStream` methods, E.g.:

```
class Something @Inject (environment: play.api.Environment) {
  // ...
  environment.resourceAsStream("data.json") map ( Json.parse(_) )
```

(Note, in this case **data.json** is inside the **conf** folder)

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.Environment

Answer (score 0):

I usually need few small dictionaries to live in memory in order to build some plain LUTs (LookUp Tables). In order to achieve that I use the following piece of code (please it is worth noting I am using latest [Play 2.6](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Home)):

```
def loadJSONFromFilename(filename: String): Option[JsValue] =
  Option(Source.fromFile(filename).mkString)
    .map(Json.parse)
```

Using the previous function is just a matter of passing a `filename` path. Tailoring this to be used with Play you might need to place your file in a resource folder and to enable it you need to place this in your `build.sbt` file:

```
// include resources into the unversal zipped package using sbt dist
mappings in Universal ++= directory(baseDirectory.value / "resources")
```

Thus, you can use this resource folder this way in your Play class:

```
lazy val lutFilePath: Path = 
  Paths.get(env.rootPath.getAbsolutePath, "resources", "lut.json")
lazy val lutJson = loadJSONFromFilename(lutFilePath.toString)
```